# Zoom on clicking a marker on a map

Tags: flutter

I'd like to zoom in when I click a marker on the map in Flutter. This is what I have so far:

```
onTap: () {
                    initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(33.582738, -7.590258),
                      zoom: 5.151926040649414,
                    );
                  },
```

These are my markers:

[image: Makers on a Google Maps image]

What should I change in my `onTap` function to zoom in on the marker?

Answer (score 0):

in your widget declare this

```
late GoogleMapController mapController;
```

In **onMapCreated** do this

```
GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
            markers: markers,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            mapToolbarEnabled: true,
            mapType: MapType.hybrid,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: true,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              mapController = controller;
            },
          ),
```

When you initialize map add mapController in it

```
onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(lat, long), 14));
                });
              },
```

Comment: how to add mapcontroller